# Integrating native map app first direct to safari

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

In my app, I have integrated native map app for showing directions between two points on button action. I am using the following code.

```
- (IBAction)showRoute
{
     NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.apple.com/maps?    daddr=%@,%@&saddr=%f,%f",d_latitude,d_longitude, s_latitude, s_longitude];
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
}
```

But the problem is when click the button it first redirects to safari and then maps app - is there any way to miss out the safari step ?

Comment: try by implementing your own `UIWebView` on button action, instead of calling openURL/safari

Comment: Requirement is to implement it on native map app

Answer (score 0):

In which iOS have you tried.? I tried on iOS 6 simulator works fine, opens the map app directly. In iOS simulator it opened safari has it doesn't have map app on simulator.

I have tried the below code on button action, its similar the one you used.

```
NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.apple.com/maps?daddr=%f,%f&saddr=Current%%20Location", 40.7142, 74.0064];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```